# how to get tot pages found in Google News (user agent from Curl doesn't work)?

Tags: r, screen-scraping, web-scraping, rcurl

For my project I need to get a day-by-day statistics of number of news (from google news) for a certain keyword. But the problem is that the results got via browser are absolutely different from what is get through RCurl. It seems that I miss some options. What should be done?
Thank you very much in advance for any hint!

here's the code (not all, just rcurl options), but the content of DPage is different from what browser shows :( :

```
    require(RCurl)
    theURL<-"http://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&q=Putin&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min%3A09.11.10%2Ccd_max%3A09.11.11&tbm=nws"
    ch <- getCurlHandle()
    curlSetOpt(curl = ch,
               ssl.verifypeer = FALSE,
               useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10",
               timeout = 60,
               followlocation = TRUE,
               cookiejar = "./cookies",
               cookiefile = "./cookies") 
DPage <- getURL(theURL, curl = ch)
```

Comment: Try Rselenium package to emulate the broser. http://johndharrison.github.io/RSelenium/

Answer (score 1):

Google has some defences to prevent automated requests that do not use its custom search API. Try using the Bing search engine URL instead with your script, they also provide a generous custom search API for developers.
`http://www.bing.com/news/search?q=putin&p1=[NewsVertical+SortByDate%3d%221%22]&FORM=YGNR`

or the its complimentry RSS feed as this will offer no resistance to being read.
`http://api.bing.com/rss.aspx?Source=News&Market=en-GB&Version=2.0&Query=putin`